# Fixed Header with autogenerate columns

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008, gridview

Is there a way to have fixed Headers with autogenerate columns?  I am against creating the headers manually since we will be using the same gridview for different information.

Also, is there a way to align a header/row differently from the rest?  Lets say I always want all the rows and header to align center except for the row "name".  Is it possible to do an if statement for that?  Or maybe there is an easier way?

I am always open to any ideas of using a different graph also.  So if anyone has any, that would be great suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public virtual bool AutoGenerateColumns { get; set; }


<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="True|False" />
```

Example:

```
<asp:sqldatasource id="CustomersSource"
  selectcommand="SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName, FirstName, LastName FROM SalesLT.Customer"
  connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AWLTConnectionString %>" 
  runat="server"/>

<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
  datasourceid="CustomersSource" 
  autogeneratecolumns="False"
  emptydatatext="No data available." 
  allowpaging="True" 
  runat="server" DataKeyNames="CustomerID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
            SortExpression="CompanyName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
            SortExpression="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
            SortExpression="LastName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Below is a link about aligning:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.horizontalalign.aspx

Below is a link about different column headers size/style:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadersdefaultcellstyle.aspx

Comment: Thats for the suggestion, but I dont think you read my questions correctly or I am not understanding the code.  It seems as if you are just calling the columns manually.  Which would mean if we inject another dataset in that doesnt have FirstName, It would error. right?

Comment: Sorry. That edit seems the same as the first. except in reference to headers